# how to see when a trigger in Sybase was fired

Tags: sybase

I need to see in Sybase version 12.5 when a trigger was fired or used
any help  please would be great, does anyone know how to please
Thank  you

Answer (score 1):

You can to use `print` in a trigger:

```
create trigger trigger_name
on table_name
for insert
print "I'm working"
```